# Serverless vs traditional web frameworks routing architecture

Tags: python, python-3.x, serverless-architecture

Just as a pure hobby side project, I am writing some code which is going to require the regular CRUD interaction from the users, via the web browser.

Naturally, to avoid reinventing the wheel, I am looking at various web frameworks and pretty much all of them have some routing logic built into them: /posts go to x, /users goes to y etc.

On the face of it, that seems like a good idea - one less thing for me to reimplement (and inevitably get wrong), on the other hand this feels like a bottleneck and a single point of failure - every client needs to hit a particular node first so it can resolve routing, this can probably be load balanced, but it feels like duplicating effort, why can't the load balancer route straight to the correct resource, making it a 1 step operation?

Now this is a hobby project and no way I can hit these problems, but just for sake of learning and getting it right the first time, are there any python3 web frameworks that do both out of the box?

Is there a way to configure a load balancer to handle routing or perhaps go the 'serverless' route (where do I define my resources in that case?)

I can use AWS Application Load Balancer, but I'd rather look for a generic solution.

Am I wrong here? Do you think these concerns should be separated or handled in one place?

Comment: Have you looked at AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda?

Comment: I have indeed, hence my question - I don't want to be locked into the AWS APIs for this, so I am wondering if open-source alternatives are already popping up and if so, what are the back-end 'serverless' servers executing the lambdas.

Comment: You can look at https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk and https://github.com/kubeless/kubeless as open-source alternatives.